# Subset of a subset of a dataframe in one row

Tags: r, dataframe

How can I, in a single statement extract the subset of a subset. Bellow an example of what I tried:

```
df = data.frame(C1 = c(1,2,3), C2 = c("V1", "V2", "V3"), C3 = c(3,2,1))
col_is_num = sapply(df, is.numeric)
col_is_num
> C1   C2    C3
  TRUE FALSE TRUE
```

Now if I want to select only the numeric columns I can do:

```
df[, col_is_num]
>   C1 C3
    1  3
    2  2
    3  1
```

But what if I want to immediatly select the second column among the column that are of type numeric at the same time that I subset them from thee full df ? I tried something like below that is not working :

```
df[, col_is_num][, 2]
> Error in 'bla-bla' undefined columns selected
```

Comment: `df[2,sapply(df, is.numeric)]`?

Answer (score 0):

I don't get the error you're getting. The code you've provided doesn't give that answer. If you want the *row* rather than the *column* you could do

```
df[2, col_is_num]
```